# jsPdf creating blank pages after page filled with data

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am using jsPdf to create pdf. I am facing a problem, it is creating extra blank pages after creating pages filled with data. It is creating extra 4 to 5 blank pages.

```js
const doc = new jsPDF({ format: 'a4' });
const source = document.getElementById("reports");
doc.setFont("arial", "normal");
doc.setFontSize(5);
doc.html(source, {
  callback: function(doc) {
    doc.save();
  },
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  width: 140,
  windowWidth: 1000,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your element proportions are not correct.

You can view this [generate-pdf-from-react-html](https://github.com/Milen-Minchev/generate-pdf-from-react-html#usage) for correct use of styles and elements sizes.